Can't enable W25Q for writing (using STM32F103)
I am trying to work with a W25Q128 and previous I got stuck with talking to the chip, but stackoverflow helped me and I was able to communicate with the chip. Now I am unable to bring the chip into Writing Mode by issuing Write Enable (0x06) command. Please find the screenshots of my logic analyzer to understand this better.
The problem is after issuing 0x06 when I read the status register 1, I see that the WEL bit is not set. During my trial and error, the WEL got set once (this implies that the chip is not bad), but I don't know exactly when it got set and how, but most of the times, it does not set.
The datasheet is confusing. Can someone help me with the proper steps of writing to and reading from this flash memory? Also do I need to erase a page before I write it to?
Resetting the chip

Releasing power down mode

Trying to write

Reading gives me all bytes as 0xFF

UPDATE
I have removed the code of WEL checking after issuing write enabale, and this time the code worked!! Shall not I check if the "Write Enable" command actually worked or not, before I move to the actual writing? Here is the code (the part of checking WEL is commented)
static uint32_t W25QXX_Write_Enable() {
    uint8_t buf[1] = { W25QXX_WRITE_ENABLE };
    if(SPI_Send(W25QXX.SPIx, buf, 1, 5)){

        //delayMs(2);
        //if((W25QXX_Get_Status_Register_1() & 0x02)){
            return 1;
        //}
    }
    return 0;
}


"The problem is after issuing 0x06 when I read the status register 1, I see that the WEL bit is not set.", but your 3rd waveform shows WEL = 1 when reading the Status Register-1. Your  statement is equally confusing.

Sorry @kaosad, I'll update the question.

Flash memory 101: "For Flash memory, you can only write 0 to a memory cell, it means that any cells that have been set to 0 by programming can only be reset to 1 by erasing the entire block".  So before you executing Page_Programming command 0x02, you must perform a Sector_Erase command 0x20 to erase all 4k-byte(a sector) first (all cells will be reset to 0xFF). You can then program any byte within the sector.

Hi @hcheung It was a brand new chip and when I read those bytes, I got 0xFF, so I thought those bytes were already erased. But, yes erasing and then programming did the trick. But the main question remains, after I issue the WRITE ENABLE command, how do I make sure that the chip actually entered into WRITING MODE (WEL bit is set)?

It has nothing to do with brand new or not, it is the flash technology that it can't write into it unless you erase it first. That's why I called it Flash Memory 101! Write_enable is a one-byte command, no data back from the slave, the only thing you can check is whether the SPI transmission is success or not.

Understood! Checking the WEL bit after issuing write enable command is really uncertain, sometimes it shows 1 (is set), some times does not. Thank you again.
